# Duda. ¿por que no me crea el archivo?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{

    struct cliente
{
       int documento;
       char nombre[20];
       char apellido[20];
       char telefono[10];
       int ocupacion;
       int sueldo;
};
    char opc;

    entrada.open("datoscliente.txt",ios::out|ios::app);
    if (entrada.fail())
    {
      cout<< "ERROR AL ABRIR EL ARCHIVO"<<endl;
     }
       else
      {
       do
         {
                      cout<<"******DATOS DE CLIENTE*******"<<endl;
                      cout<<endl;
                      cout<<"DOCUMENTO: ";
                      cin>> documeto;
                      cout<<"NOMBRE:  ";
                      cin>>nombre;
                      cout<<"APELLIDOS:  ";
                      cin>>apellidos;
                      cout<<"SUELDO:  ";
                      cin>>sueldo;
                      entrada<<codigo<<" "<<nombre<<" "<<apellidos<<" "<<sueldo<<endl;
                      cout<<endl;
                      cout<<"desea continuar ingresando datos si 1/ no 2"<<endl;
                      cin>>opc;
                      opc=toupper(opc);
         }while (opc == 2);
     }
   entrada.close();               
  system ("pausa");
return (0);                     
}
```

Comment: que quieres decir con que no crea el archivo? no guarda datos, o directamente nunca aparece?

Comment: Que no te crea el archivo quiere decir... ¿Que no crea físicamente el archivo y aparece un error? ¿Que no crea físicamente el archivo pero no da error? ¿Que el archivo se crea pero está vacío? ...

Comment: No me aparece el archivo, y me da error donde dice documentos! Noo se por que

Comment: @PedroAntonioObregonAlomia ¿Podrías indicar que tipo de error te está generando?

Answer (score 0):

Fijate que estas mandando a la salida:

```
entrada<<codigo<<" "<<nombre<<" "<<apellidos<<" "<<sueldo<<endl;
```

y codigo no existe.. pero si existe documento.. seguro tu problema esta ahi.

Comment: Ya lo corregi y sigue mandando el mismo error.

Comment: Y cual es el error? nunca lo especificaste